# RaspberryPi ZeroW にＧＰＳ受信機キットを接続したが緯度経度が測定失敗する

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gps

### やりたいこと

RaspberryPiにGPSモジュールを接続して緯度経度を出力したい

### 環境

- ハードは RaspberryPi ZeroWH
- OS は RASPBIAN STRETCH LITE
- GPSモジュール
  -- ＧＰＳ受信機キット　１ＰＰＳ出力付き　「みちびき」３機受信対応(http://akizukidenshi.com/catalog/g/gK-09991/)
  -- GT-902PMGG 「ＧＰＳ／ＧＬＯＮＡＳＳ受信機（Ｇａｌｉｌｅｏ／ＢｅｉＤｏｕ可）ｕ‐ｂｌｏｘ　Ｍ８搭載　みちびき３機受信対応」(http://akizukidenshi.com/catalog/g/gM-12905/)

### 変更した点：

基本的には以下ページの８～１３まで
https://gist.github.com/CLCL/e0f840461e20a3a83179b4941d45c203

- UART設定
  -- `# raspi-config nonint do_serial 1`
  -- /boot/config.txt 内の enable_uartを1へ変更
- /dev/gps0 の設定

  ```
  # stty -F /dev/ttyS0 ispeed 9600
  # cat << 'EOS' | tee /etc/udev/rules.d/40-selialgps.rules
  KERNEL=="ttyS0", SYMLINK+="gps0"
  EOS
  ```
- gpsd のインストール

  ```
  apt-get -y install gpsd gpsd-clients
  ```
- gpsdの設定

  ```
  cat << EOS | sudo tee -a  /etc/default/gpsd
  USBAUTO="false"
  DEVICES="/dev/gps0"
  EOS
  ```

### 確認したこと：

-- ＧＰＳ／ＧＬＯＮＡＳＳ受信機（Ｇａｌｉｌｅｏ／ＢｅｉＤｏｕ可）ｕ‐ｂｌｏｘ　Ｍ８搭載　みちびき３機受信対応 を接続したとき

```
    # cat /dev/gps0 
    C,V,,,,,,,,,,N*4D
    $GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
    $GNGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*56
    $GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*2E
    $GNGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*2E
    $GPGSV,1,1,01,16,,,09*76
    $GLGSV,1,1,00*65
    $GNGLL,,,,,,V,N*7A
    $GNRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*4D
    $GNVTG,,,,,,,,,N*2E
```

-- ＧＰＳ受信機キット　１ＰＰＳ出力付き　「みちびき」３機受信対応 を接続したとき

```
    # cat /dev/gps0 
    $GPGGA,000044.799,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4F
    $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
    $GPRMC,000044.799,V,,,,,0.00,0.00,050180,,,N*46
    $GPZDA,000044.799,05,01,3880,,*56
    $GPGRS,000044.799,1,,,,,,,,,,,,*79
    $GPGST,000044.799,0.000,99999,99999,00.0,99999,99999,99999*47
    $GPGGA,000045.799,,,,,0,0,,,M,,M,,*4E
    $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
```

### 質問したいこと：

- /dev/gps0 には出力されているのでgpsライブラリの設定は問題ないという認識で問題ないでしょうか？
- スマートフォンのGPSは届くのになぜ$GNRMCが V（警告）から変わらないのでしょうか？

不足している情報等ありましたらコメントお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。

- /dev/gps0 には出力されているのでgpsライブラリの設定は問題ないという認識で問題ないでしょうか？
  -- 問題ありませんでした。上記ログのように出力されていれば設定関連はOKです
- スマートフォンのGPSは届くのになぜ$GNRMCが V（警告）から変わらないのでしょうか？
  -- 空がよく見える場所で数分バッテリーで置いたところ問題なく受信できました。部屋の中（かつマンションの1F）では受信できなかったみたいです。